# Can you make a maven plugin pull in another plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm working on a plugin that will push a package file to a custom CI/CD service for automated deploys and I'd like to utilize the [build number plugin's](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) functionality for creating build numbers. Is there a way for me to make my plugin pull the build number plugin into a project that it's being used in?

Comment: It's all open source. You could just use the build plugin's code...

Answer (score 1):

You can put them both in your plugins declaration, each with it's own phase. When you add your own custom plugin, you can pass {buildnumber} into your plugin configuration, similar to what you would do when you use the jar/war plugin to include buildnumber.